# Is a structure variable declared before the semicolon of a structure declaration a global variable?

Tags: c++

Is a variable declared right after the definition of a structure a global variable or a local variable?

```
struct student {
    int id; 
    char name [ 20 ];
} stud;
```

Is `stud` a global or a local variable?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to your question and reformulate it (preferably with code samples) in order to get an (useful) answer.

Comment: Please edit your post with an example text.  Do not post images.

Comment: Since C++ allows you to define local and inner tagged types...

Answer (score 9):

It can be either global or local. This depends on where the struct-variable is defined:

**global**

```
struct Foo {
    ...
} foo;

int main() {
    return 0;
};
```

**local**

```
int main() {
    struct Foo {
        ...
    } foo;
    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No. The variable has the same scope as if you had defined it on the next line.